# How do I override / add to the Password Broker in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.2

I need to overwrite a couple of pieces of functionality / add some new stuff to the password reset process. I've know I can overwrite the functionality in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords` using the Password Controller that comes out of the tin.

I also need to make changes in `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker`. My goal is to have an invitation email for setting an initial password that uses the existing password reset functionality. The only problem is in the function `sendResetLink`.

This function gets the password token and sends the email via the reset password email view. I still need the password reset functionality, but I can't have an invitation email with 'reset your password' verbiage.

How can I do this? I think I can duplicate and tweak the functionality on the reset classes to use an invite view for the email, but I can't figure out how to extend the broker class to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the same thing. I added a setEmailView() method to my custom PasswordBroker and called that just before sending the resetlink in AuthController, but that broke the regular password reset function.
So, I scrapped all that and went for a much simpler approach. In AuthController.php, inject a variable into the password template.

```
view()->composer('auth.emails.password', function($view) {
    $view->with(['register'=>true]);
});
Password::sendResetLink(['email'=>$data['email']], function($message) {
    $message->subject('Registration Email');
});
```

Then, in the template auth/emails/password.blade.php

```
@if ( isset($register) )
    Whatever you want to say in registration Email.
@else
    Normal password reset Email here.
@endif
```